# Get notified when a method in a Singleton class is fired

Tags: java, singleton

I have a singleton class within a jar file. Let's take the following class as an example.

```
class Singleton{
    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton(){}

    public static Singleton getInstance(){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new Singleton();
        return instance;
    }

    public int addTwoNumbers(int num1, int num2){
        return num1+num2;
    }
```

Now I want to know whenever the addTwoNumbers method is fired, along with the parameters passed into it. Overriding the method is not an option since it is a in singleton. Also, since it's in a jar file, I couldn't modify it. Thus using observer pattern is also not an option. Is there any way I could possibly do this?

Thanks.

Comment: is your code only client of this singleton? If yes I can provide some solution. But if the classes in jar file using the singleton that may not work. Let me know if that will work for you?

Comment: @AlexandreSantos You mean Aspect Oriented Programming? Do we have to go to such lengths for this?

Comment: @vkg I'm not sure what you mean. This jar I'm talking about is a library that I've imported. My code is definitely separated from it.

Comment: What I mean is that in your code we handle that when ever your code calls addTwoNumbers you will get notified.

Comment: @vkg Whenever some other method calls addTwoNumbers I want to get notified along with the parameters

Comment: If you cannot control the library nor the client code you'll have to stick with something like AspectJ. If you can control the client side use a decorator or create a facade. But you'll have to touch all places in the code where the library is used if you are not able to easily inject a substitute.

Answer (score 0):

Reimplement the singleton class by yourself, and add an observer capability to it. Use the exact same package, class and method names, and make sure the jar/directory containing the new singleton is before the one containing the old singleton in the classpath.

Or modify the byte-code of the existing singleton.